# Simulating UINavigation push issues?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have two views in one XIB I want to switch, but I don't want to use a UINavigationController for this, because it's horribly inefficient because there is only one transition that will need to occur. Here's my code:

```
// get the view that's currently showing
UIView *currentView = self.view;
// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view view
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[theWindow addSubview:webViewTwo];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

.h

```
@class WebViewTwo;
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet WebViewTwo *webViewTwo;
}
```

Now it's crashing with an error

```
2011-05-12 16:59:59.528 TableView[36627:207] -[WebViewTwo superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x603b660
2011-05-12 16:59:59.531 TableView[36627:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebViewTwo superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x603b660'
```

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error would tend suggest that either `WebViewTwo` is not a subclass of `UIView` or has perviously been released and is no longer pointing to an object that is subclass of `UIView`. Check the header file where you define `WebViewTwo` and perhaps add `NSLog(@"%@", webViewTwo);` before you add it as a subview just to see what type it is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not nil and hasn't been released... Got this: `<WebViewTwo: 0x935d8d0>`. I have this in my WebViewTwo.h `@interface WebViewTwo : UIViewController {`... How do I change it and subclass it to a UIView?

Comment: Just kidding. If anyone else has this problem, simply create a IBOutlet of a UIView and connect it with your view and show it!